# Read the workflow history list during the lifetime of sp designer 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer

am using the Log to `History List`  in `SharePoint Designer workflow` action to write messages to the workflow history list during the lifetime of a workflow. because i need these messages serving as a way to report the status of the workflow back to the user.

but, my question  is how to read these messages from this wf history list and manipulate further?

Answer (score 1):

In the current site collection or subsite, just add this to the end of the URL.

```
/lists/Workflow%20History

http://contoso/sites/sitename/lists/Workflow%20History
```

Comment: how can i READ the mesages from this list  and how can i manipulate with this info?

Comment: Well, it's a list so you should be able to access it from SPD and add a workflow to it to copy data/logs to anywhere else as you got the list item id if you need to do any matching. Or do you want to get the data with REST or anything else?